# How do I replace comma with a line break in a views field?

Tags: 7, theming, views

I am working with a custom view handler that renders a comma separated list.  This field is used throughout the site this way.

Now, I have a new view that needs to render the list using line breaks instead of commas. Is there a way to do this in the view settings?

I don't want to hard-code the new view name in the view handler code to render it differently. Do I have to create a views template to solve this?

Comment: I think that you should create a views template, if you edit with more info will be better to understand the situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to create an additional options form field for your views field.
Which is done using the `options_form` and `options_definition` methods. This will allow you save a value using the options form and access that value in the render method.

```
class my_handler_my_field extends views_handler_field {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   *
   * Perform any database or cache data retrieval here. In this example there is
   * none.
   */
  function query() {

  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   *
   * Modify any end user views settings here. Debug $options to view the field
   * settings you can change.
   */
  function option_definition() {
    $options = parent::option_definition();
    $options['separator'] = array('default' => ', ');
    return $options;
  }

  function options_form(&$form, &$form_state) {
    parent::options_form($form, $form_state);

    $form['separator'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('My Field'),
      '#default_value' => $this->options['separator'],
    );

    // The path is set by render_link function so don't allow to set it.
    $form['alter']['path'] = array('#access' => FALSE);
    $form['alter']['external'] = array('#access' => FALSE);

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * Render callback handler.
   *
   * Return the markup that will appear in the rendered field.
   */
  function render($values) {
    $separator = !empty($this->options['separator']) ? $this->options['separator'] : ', ';
    ......
    return $rendered_value_with_the_right_separator;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `options_form()` method on your field handler to provide a setting. That setting could be a text field in which you enter separator to be used, `,` or `<br>` or whatever you need. Or that setting could be a select list that contained only `,` and `<br>` options.

Here is an example of an field handler that uses that method:

http://cgit.drupalcode.org/views/tree/modules/node/views_handler_field_node_link.inc?h=7.x-3.13

The key pieces are the `options_form()`

```
  function options_form(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $form['text'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Text to display'),
      '#default_value' => $this->options['text'],
    );
    parent::options_form($form, $form_state);

    // The path is set by render_link function so don't allow to set it.
    $form['alter']['path'] = array('#access' => FALSE);
    $form['alter']['external'] = array('#access' => FALSE);
  }
```

and then the usage of the option

```
  $text = !empty($this->options['text']) ? $this->options['text'] : t('view');
```

Comment: I understand where you are headed with this.  I also see a "Separator" field under settings.  How can I access that field from the handler? I feel that would be a more appropriate field to save the separator.

Comment: `$this->options` contains all of the values that are saved to options in `options_form()`

Comment: +1 for pointing me in the right direction.  I needed the `option_definition` method in conjunction with `options_form`.  Otherwise the value does not get saved.